# How to use the variable to replace the Object/OU Path with LDAPFilter in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to retrieve the membership for a specific office of one specific security group in our working environment, instead of `Get-ADGroupMember` which is slow and always get `time-out` when there is a huge user list.

My code is as below:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
**$groupinfo** = Get-ADGroup -identity "vip"

Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectcategory=user)(memberof='**$groupinfo.DistinguishedName**'))' -Properties office,title | where {$_.office -like 'New York'} | select name,samaccountname,office,title |Export-csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\NY.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

I get the following error

```
Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '**CN=vip,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com**'.
At line:2 char:2
+  Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectcategory=user)(memberof='$group.Dis ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Can anyone advise me how to use this variable `$groupinfo` in `LDAPFilter`?
Do I need a junction?

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectcategory=user)(memberof=**CN=vip,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com**))' -Properties office,title | where {$_.office -like 'New York'} | select name,samaccountname,office,title |Export-csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\NY.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

This one does work when no variable.

Comment: Did you put in the double asterikses `**` as a means of making that text bold or??

Comment: Yes, making that text bold, however it is not showing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use double-quotes around the `LDAPFilter`, the content of the variable is used instead of the variable name literal.

Try:

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=$($groupinfo.DistinguishedName)))" -Properties office,title | 
    Where-Object {$_.office -like '*New York*'} | 
    Select-Object name,samaccountname,office,title |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\NY.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

<sup>Note: I have not tried to put all this in a single ling, because doing that just askes for mistakes that are hard to spot. Also, I changed `(objectcategory=user)` to `(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)` to make sure only user objects are returned. See [Filter on objectCategory and objectClasO](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Filter_on_objectCategory_and_objectClass)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, new to the forum. I have marked as the answer.